# Sql Select from two tables in single query

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

I have Two Tables as under

```
        SalesDetails                          PurchaseDetails 
Date   SaleOrderId ProductId Qty       Date    PurcsOrderId ProductId    Qty 
2/2/12 S_1           P_1       4       1/2/12   PO_1          P_1       50
3/2/12 S_2           P_1       5       4/2/12   PO_2          P_1       50   
3/2/12 S_2           P_2       7       
6/2/12 S_3           P_1       3
9/2/12 S_4             1       5

from these two tables i want to show a report like this
         Product Inquiry Report 
             ProductId: P_1
Date     TrId Debit    Credit   
1/2/12   PO_1  50                
2/2/12   S_1            4   
3/2/12   S_2            5
4/2/12   PO_2  50   
6/2/12   S_3            3
```

Here Qty column of purchasedetails becomes 'Debit' in the report and Qty in SalesDetails becomes 'Credit' column in Report.In report, the transaction should be shown in order to Date as shown Is there a way to perform this in a single query, if yes, then how? if no, then is there any other solution? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ece3c/8/0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
  SELECT sa.Date, sa.SaleOrderId AS TRId, Null AS Debit, sa.Qty AS Credit
  FROM SalesDetails sa
  UNION
  SELECT pa.Date, pa.PurcsOrderId AS TRId, pa.Qty AS Debit, Null AS Credit
  FROM PurchaseDetails pa
) m
ORDER BY 1
```

If you would rather the values be `0` then use `0 AS Debit` and `0 AS Credit` respectively.

Comment: Its a more explained form of Bulat's answer. Thanks @Linger :)

Answer (score 3):

Use UNION:

```
SELECT Date, SaleOrderID as TrId, NULL as Debit, Qty as Credit 
FROM SalesDetails
UNION
SELECT Date, PurcsOrderId AS TrId, Qty AS Debit, NULL as Credit
FROM PurchaseDetails
ORDER BY Date
```

Comment: Thanks V much @Bullat. Its a beautiful logic